# ora-01830:la mascara de formato de fecha termina

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Buenas tengo un problema al lanzar la query siguiente. Quiero traer todos los recibos emitidos en el intervalo de fecha.

```
SELECT COUNT(FCHA_EMSION) AS TotalMesFebrero
FROM PREDIAL.DOCUMENTOS 
WHERE FCHA_EMSION BETWEEN '01/02/2017' AND '30/02/2017';
```

Error:

> ORA-01830ERROR: La mascar de formato de fecha termina antes de convertir toda la cadena.

Comment: Que tipo de dato es el campo `FCHA_EMSION`?

Comment: El problema de trabajar con fechas es el formato. Para los europeos, es DD/MM/YYYY, mientras que paras los noteramericanos es MM/DD/YYYY. La primera fecha se la tragó porque era 01/02 (que al revés sería 02/01), pero la segunda no, porque no hay mes 30 para convertir.

Answer (score 3):

El error que te esta dando es porque no le agregaste la mascara a la consulta te dejo un ejemplo y usar `TO_DATE`

```
  SELECT COUNT(FCHA_EMSION) AS TotalMesFebrero
    FROM PREDIAL.DOCUMENTOS 
     WHERE FCHA_EMSION BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/02/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
AND TO_DATE('30/02/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```